# set delegate and data source of UItableview in custom UIview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a custom `UIView`, which has a few different views, AND a `UITableview`.

I have created a custom class which is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. this will control the `UITableview` and the Prototype cell for the `UITableView`.

If i set the *delegate* and *datasource* to the parent view, I get the following error:

```
-[RoadSafetyAppViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c92f190
```

where RoadSafetyAppView Controller is the parent view. However, if i don't set a delegate and data source at all, my table doesn't load the images i have declared in my custom class, which is given below:

```
@implementation MenuController
@synthesize menuArray;

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.menuArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
    [menuArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dob in a Hoon menu.png"]];
    [menuArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Report a Hazard menu.png"]];
    [menuArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Old Logo menu.png"]];
    [menuArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Council Website menu.png"]];
}


-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.menuArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    MenuCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    cell.menuImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dob in a Hoon menu.png"];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.menuImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dob in a Hoon menu.png"];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.menuImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Report a Hazard menu.png"];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.menuImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Old Logo menu.png"];
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.menuImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Council Website menu.png"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Can someone either point out where i am going wrong with my images, or what i need to set my delegate/data source to?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you should be setting your `delegate` and `dataSource` to your `MenuController` instance, not `RoadSafetyAppViewController`.

Comment: Is `RoadSafetyAppViewController` is the parent of `MenuController`? Set the `delegate` and `datasource` to `MenuController` and check.

Comment: is menuArray initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: See connections for UITableView]At your MenuController.h

```
MenuController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

And connect UITableView with Delegate&Datasource at Interface Builder..

Hope it fixes your issue..!

Comment: I can't control+drag from tableview to Delegate or Datasource.

Comment: you need to declare Delegates as above to make it control+drag from tableview to Delegate & Datasource...!

Comment: i have amended my .h file as you have suggested, but still cant drag from my table view datasource to the tableview.

Comment: Have you set your file owner to MenuViewController at Interface Builder..PLZ check..That may be issue..!

Comment: i do, but overtime i leave the identity inspector, the custom class changes back to UITableview.

Comment: As @Vidhyanand900 said, you need the File's Owner to be of class `MenuController`. This means you need the previous custom class to be of class `UIViewController`. If your File's Owner is `UIViewTable` then your XIB only defines your view and not your view controller. Where is your `MenuController` instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

Set delegate and datasouce by coding in viewDidLoad method of MenuController

```
_tblView.delegate = self;
_tblView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: I can't do this as for some reason, i can't link my IBoutlet to the tableview. the control+drag doesn't let me select the iboutliet in my .hfile